Commutators of unbounded operators on Hilbert spaces
Commutation seems to be a tricky business when it comes to unbounded operators, because of the domain questions. I have some trouble understanding the usual material about commutators of unbounded operators and have a few questions.
In the self adjoint case : to avoid domain problems, commutation for unbounded self-adjoint operators is often defined as the commutation of the spectral resolutions, and it is stated that it is stronger than pointwise commutativity on a common core for $A$ and $B$, with the example of Nelson (see e.g. Reed-Simon volume 1 section VIII.5). But this is not the stronger hypothesis one could make : what if $AB$ and $BA$ were densely defined, closable, and agreeing on a common core for their closures (meaning that their closures are equal) ? Wouldn't that give the commutativity of the spectral resolutions ?
In the closed case : dropping the self-adjoint assumption, imagine you have $A$, $B$ closed unbounded operators on an Hilbert space. Assume $[A,B] = C$ on a dense subset $D$, where $C$ with domain $D$ is a closable operator. Let $\overline{C}$ the closure of $C$.
Take for instance some $\psi \in D(BA) \cap D(\overline{C})$ with $\psi \notin D(AB)$. Does it make sense to "extend" $AB$ for such a $\psi$ as $AB\psi = \overline{C}\psi + BA\psi$ ? Isn't it weird to have a commutator potentially defined on vectors that are neither in $D(A)$ nor in $D(B)$ ?
